# CSVProvider start reading csv at specific row

Tags: csv, f#, f#-data

I want to read a csv file with using FSharp.Data CSVProvider.

The data looks like:

```
;Datum;Von;bis;MW
Maximum;16.10.2015;19:00;19:15;9268,000
Minimum;26.12.2015;13:30;13:45;-5195,000

"Datum";"Von";"bis";"Vertikale Netzlast [MW]";
01.01.2015;00:00;00:15;1.216;
01.01.2015;00:15;00:30;1.121;
01.01.2015;00:30;00:45;1.090;
01.01.2015;00:45;01:00;981;
```

I want to use the following code:

```
let csvValues = CsvProvider<"http://ws.50hertz.com/web01/api/PhotovoltaicForecast/DownloadFile?fileName=2015.csv&callback=?", ";">.GetSample()
```

How can I start to read the file at row 5 or if the first column contains "Datum"?

Comment: @GuyCoder Firstly I'm not new and secondly I accepted at almost all questions the correct answer? Which question do you mean!?

Comment: You should search on the keyword `slice` for list or seq. That should give you an idea.

Comment: your right. I did not see the other pages.

Comment: It looks like CSVProvider uses `Skip` and/or `Take` for slicing See: [F# Data: CSV Type Provider](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/CsvProvider.html) under Transforming CSV files

Comment: @GuyCoder Yeah, I found that before, but I made a mistake. I had to negate the bool argument in SkipWhile. Now it is working.

Comment: Glad you have it working and posted your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is working with SkipWhile:

```
let csvValues = CsvProvider<"http://ws.50hertz.com/web01/api/PhotovoltaicForecast/DownloadFile?fileName=2015.csv&callback=?", ";", IgnoreErrors=true>.GetSample()
                    .SkipWhile(fun r -> not (r.Column1.Contains("Datum")))
```

Or this is also working, with an option in constructor to skip rows:

```
let csvValues = CsvProvider<"http://ws.50hertz.com/web01/api/PhotovoltaicForecast/DownloadFile?fileName=2015.csv&callback=?", ";", IgnoreErrors=true, SkipRows=3>.GetSample()
```